# Decompose into simple fractions $\frac{f'}{f}$

Tags: derivatives, partial-fractions

Let $f(x) = (x-a_1)(x-a_2)...(x-a_n)$.

Find a decomposition into simple fractions of $\frac{f'}{f}$.

Where $f'$ is a derivative of our polynomial.

As I understand, we have to find a pretty-format of $f'$ and then task will be easy. But I have no idea how to find this.

Note that some $a_i$ can be equal to each other.

Comment: Suggestion: Compute it for several small $n$ and look for a pattern.

Comment: It might help to recognize that (fgh)'=f'gh+fg'h+fgh', and I'm sure you can see the generalization to n factors.

Comment: *Hint:* $f'/f = (\log f)'$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Martin's idea,

Let for $ x\ne a_1,a_2,...,a_n $,
$$g(x)=\ln(|f(x)|)=$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(|x-a_k|)$$

thus

$$g'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{x-a_k}$$